# remove string from an array of images using a HTML form

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

i have records stored in a MySQL Database. the images are stored like:

`[image1.jpg],[image2.jpg],[image3.jpg]` ...etc

I am selecting rows using a SQL Select query and then:

```
$images = explode(',',$project['images']);
```

to explode each image (separated by a ,)

then i have:

```
<?php
        foreach($images as $image)
        {
            $display_image = substr($image, 1, -1);
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="/img/project-gallery/<?php echo $display_image; ?>" width="160px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
```

how can i use a HTML checkbox in a form to delete images (only the selected) like the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="images[]" id="images[]" />
```

Comment: @AlexP obviously - well observed :)

Comment: My point is that you have asked for a "how can i use a HTML checkbox in a form to delete images" yet the question title  and code have nothing to do with a form. You might need to clarify what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question, so I'll only address the HTML part.

You want to add an `<input>` element next to each image... something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input name="images_to_delete[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $display_image; ?>" />
        <img src="/img/project-gallery/<?php echo $display_image; ?>" width="160px" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

And you need to surround this table/list with a `<form>` tag. You also need a php page to handle the submission of this form, but I'll leave that to you.

In PHP, once you get the `$images_to_delete` array, this is one method you can remove the images from the original $images string:

```
$images = "," . $images . ","; // add comma to beginning and end of list

foreach ($images_to_delete as $image_to_delete) {
    str_replace("," . $image_to_delete . ",", ","); // e.g. replaces ",image1.jpg," with ","
}

$images = substr($images, 1, -1); // remove comma from beginning and end
```

Comment: And you're downvoting this why?

Comment: i need to be able to remove the string using PHP

Comment: i didnt - not sure who did

Comment: I added one way to do what you want in PHP... let me know if that's what you needed.

Comment: Can you please comment to say whether or not this worked for you?

Comment: no - what is $images = "," . $images . ","; ? and where do i need to run the SQL Update query to remove the filename in the database?

Comment: There's a comment at the end of the line to explain what it does; it simply adds a comma to the beginning and end of the original string list of images, just to make processing easy. The details don't really matter... what you want is simply to update the images list in your database with the value of the `$images` variable at the end of my code (which is a string of image names separated by commas, like the original list but with the specified images deleted from it).

Answer (score 0):

I would have to tell you that you shouldn't store images itself in database, it's considered to be a bad practice! Keep your images on the disk in some folder and have only a record about the image in database with its path, size or whatever parameters you would want.

You must first assign a unique id to each image dynamically, and eventually make it look like `image_id_checkbox_1` or `image_id_checkbox_2` and so on.

Do something like this with PHP to prosses post request and to only *get checked* images :

```
if (isset($_POST['delete_selected_images'])) {
    $index = 0;
    foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
        if ( substr($key, 0, 18) == 'image_id_checkbox_') {
            if ( $value == 'on' ) {
                deleteImage(str_replace('image_id_checkbox_', '', $key));
                ++$index;
            }
        }
    }
```

The `deleteImage` function should do something like this:

```
function deleteImage( $image_id )
{   
  $image = $config['images_path']. '/' .$image_id. '.jpg';
  if ( file_exists($image) ) {
      @chmod($image, 0777);
      @unlink($image);
  }  
}
```

Comment: what about removing the filename from the database

Comment: oh, :) it's in database, right! Well, just perform update query on selected images, instead of firing `deleteImage` function.

Comment: the image names are in the database like [image1.jpg],[image2.jpg],[image2.jpg], ...

Comment: What you show is probably a link to your image and not the image it self? You would have to show you SQL table.. It's a very long story really. Not very hard though! It's much harder to process POST request properly. Don't store images in database, my friend, it's considered to be a bad practice!

Comment: where else do i store the images then lol? i need to be able to remove for example [image1.jpg], from the images column if that image is selected

Comment: You keep images itself on the disk, in some folder and have only a records about images in database, like path, size and so on!

Comment: well, you cannot keep physical files in a database, i am only storing the paths

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Read the question again, the **string** is stored in the database not the images

Comment: I could offer him a workaround if I saw the table and its structure. Based on my example above all he needs is to replace `deleteImage` with proper SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be storing your images within a single database field, it is a one-to-many relationship.

You need to create a separate table so you can uniquely reference each image by a primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE `product_images` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `src` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**Update** If you **have** to do it this way (I recommend you don't)

```
$string = 'image1.jpg,image2.jpg,image2.jpg';
$images = explode(',', $string);

if (isset($_POST['images'])) {
    foreach($_POST['images'] as $name => $value) {
        if (in_array($name, $images)) unset($images[$name]);
    }
    $string = implode(',', array_values($images));
    // update the database with new string
}

foreach($images as $image) {
  echo '<tr><td>';
  printf('<input type="checkbox" name="images[%s]" value="%s"/>', $image, $image);
  printf('<img src="/img/project-gallery/%s"/>', $image);
  echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: i have a whole website that has been coded this way - it would take me days to change it all round

Comment: i am just looking for a way to remove the selected image filename(s) from the images column in my database

Comment: @charlie I've updated, it's still unfinished anyway (**you** need to wrap it in a form tags). Understand the approach, and why I think this is not a great solution.

Comment: whats the %s in the checkboxes?